# How do I get vim omnicompletion to support php class methods using ::

Tags: php, vim, autocomplete

Using vim + php + ctags I can get fairly good php auto-completion. But one part really eludes me: getting vim to auto-complete class methods. Here's an example:

The full method is

```
CVarDumper::dumpAsString
```

And I want it to complete if I type this:

```
CVarDumper::d<tab>
```

The double-colon does not work. However, if I replace the `::` with a `.` then it does autocomplete:

```
CVarDumper.d<tab>
```

I see the [c++ omnifunc](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion) function has an option to allow for `::` completion:

```
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 " autocomplete after ::
```

Is there an equivalent for the `ft-php-omni` function, or a way to hack this feature in?

---

Update:

Turns out the problem was the [supertab plugin](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab), specifically this option in my .vimrc

```
" SuperTab option for context aware completion                                                                          
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
```

After removing that option [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) + [phpcomplete](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim) allows for completion of php class methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this alternative `phpcomplete` script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171). It is better than the default one in every possible ways, including the fact that it supports static completion.

Comment: I gave that script a try, and it is very good, but only completed after the arrow notation -> and not after the :: mark. Is there perhaps a configuration option to that script that I missed?

Comment: After manually going through all my plugins it appears the [supertab plugin](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) interferes with the static completion. After disabling supertab I have proper static completion.