# vim php omnicompletion not showing classes

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I tried setting up omnicompletion in vim for a yii project. For this, I go yii/framework folder and create ctags file with `ctags-exuberant -f yii.tags --languages=PHP -R`
Now in .vimrc, I added the yii.tags file with `:set tags=~/public_html/yii/framework/yii.tags`

On opening the tags file shows all classes.

However, when I open a file and hit `C-x, C-o` , the dropdown list contains only functions and variables. I couldn't find similar problem on the search. What could I be missing?

Comment: You could try [this alternative `phpcomplete.vim`](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `:help ft-php-omni`, the default omnicomplete script for PHP (the one that is part of the standard vim distribution) only completes class names after the `new` keyword.  Does that work?

If you want method completion to be restricted to the correct class, then you may have to add hints in the comments.  The docs include the example

```
/* @var $myVar myClass */
$myVar->
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have just read the manual. Do you know any vim command for completing class names anywhere. This shall be useful for static references to class variables and functions.

Comment: Found the solution to class anywhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328870/how-do-i-get-vim-omnicompletion-to-support-php-class-methods-using